# Passport Local Strategy Login with Password

Tags: mongodb, express, passport.js

When the user tries to log in, the password that is being compared to the compare method of the Student model doesn't hash it.

For example, the value of `candidatePassword` is the String password the user enters which is compared to `this.password`, which is a hashed value of the password, thus logging, `wrong password` in console.

Not sure how to fix it exactly.

```
studentSchema.pre('save', function save(next) {
  const student = this;

  if (!student.isModified('password')) {
    return next();
  }

  bcrypt.genSalt(10, (err, salt) => {
    if (err) {
      return next(err);
    }

    bcrypt.hash(student.password, salt, (err, hash) => {
      if (err) {
        return next(err);
      }
      student.password = hash;
      next();
    });
  });
});
```

`ComparePassword`

```
studentSchema.methods.comparePassword = function (candidatePassword) {
  bcrypt.compareSync(candidatePassword, this.password, (err, isMatch) => {
    if (err) {
        return err;
    }

    return isMatch;
});
```

};

`LocalStrategy`

```
passport.use('local', new LocalStrategy({
  usernameField: 'email'
}, async (email, password, done) => {
  const userFound = await STUDENT
    .findOne({ email: email.toLowerCase() })
    .populate([ '_college', 'enrolledClasses' ]);

  if (!userFound) {
    console.log('User Does Not Exist');
    return done(null, false, 'User Does Not Exist');
  }

  if (!userFound.comparePassword(password)) {
    console.log('Wrong Password'); // getting this error
    return done(null, false, 'Wrong Password.');
  }
  return done(null, userFound);
}));
```

`Login`

```
app.post('/auth/login', passport.authenticate('local', {
  successRedirect: '/home',
  failureRedirect: '/login'
}));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`bcrypt.compareSync` does not take in the `callback`. It returns `boolean` value. So:

```
 studentSchema.methods.comparePassword = function (candidatePassword) {
   return bcrypt.compareSync(candidatePassword, this.password);
 }
```